# Unable to install Composer - php-fpm

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, composer-php

Finally got Ubuntu 12.10 with nginx and php-fpm up and running.  Now I want to run a websocket server with Ratchet, but I need to install Composer first.  So I do this:

```
 curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Just as the Composer site instructed, but I received the following error:

```
The program 'php' is currently not installed.
```

I thought it might have something to do with the php at the end there so I changed it to php5-fpm and then it told me:

```
[18-Nov-2012 05:01:30] ERROR: An another FPM instance seems to already listen on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
[18-Nov-2012 05:01:30] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

Has anyone else encountered this?  Any solutions?  Thanks.

Comment: As a side note: plz don't pipe internet straight to execution. It is unsafe, as there may happen a lot of things in transport. For example, your connection may temporarily break, and you are then piping an unfinished, partial file to php. So: always first get the full code down and then run it.

Answer (score 7):

composer needs at least php 5.3.2. what's your php version? You need php command line to make it work. As the error msg suggested, you'd better install 'php'. In ubuntu, you can use

```
  sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Answer (score 4):

use

```
usr/bin/php or /usr/bin/php instead of php
```

if you are not sure where your php is located, do a check via

```
whereis php
```

Comment: by using `whereis php` I could found my php installation as successfully installed composer.phar utilizing it . Huge thanks. Gr8 Gr8 Gr8.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have php5-cli installed?

```
dpkg -l | grep php5-cli
```

If not, type

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Comment: Do both php-fpm and php-cli share the same dependencies? If I install composer using that, will the dependencies installed with Composer work for php-fpm?

Comment: @jreed121: not sure, but it's clear the installer requires the php-cli.

Comment: @jreed121 composer resolves dependencies on the package level. So it works for both projects created for either php-fpm or php-cli.